# jQuery Scroll event firing without actually scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website has pages that dynamically load content without having to change pages. I have the following jquery plugin created in my javascript file which should do certain things when the page is scrolled to the bottom.

```
$.fn.scrollEvent= function() {
    $(document).on("scroll", function() {
        console.log("Scroll");
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            // do stuff
        }
    });
};
```

So when a menu item is clicked, I load the new page content and I call the jquery plugin so it can be used on the new page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".menu-item", function() {
        $.fn.scrollEvent();
        // do other page stuff
    });
});
```

However, what i'm noticing is that when I call the plugin, the console is logging "Scroll" before I do anything on the page. So the scrolling event is being called once or even twice without me actually scrolling at all.

Why this is this happening? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use following pattern:

```
$.fn.scrollEvent = function () {
    return this.on("scroll", function () {
        console.log("Scroll");
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            // do stuff
        }
    });
};

$(window).scrollEvent(); //bind event to windwo or any element
```

Comment: Caching $(window) and $(document) outside of the scroll event and using === instead of == will help scrolling performance here.